# White patches on chilli plant leaves - leaves dying

Tags: leaves, chili, damage

I've moved my chili plants to a brand new greenhouse after growing them from seed indoors and within days they've developed these white patches on the leaves, some of them followed by chlorosis and and then leaves dying.

I've sprayed them with a 10% milk solution and that seemed to do it for a couple of days but now they're degrading again. The white residue you see in the photos is the dried up milk solution. I've also sprayed them with store-bought fungus killer 2 days later but I think they're still dying.

There was nothing in the greenhouse before but being a complete noob I left them in there with a lot of humidity in the first 2 nights (droplets on the windows). Still, the spray + milk solution should have handled the mildew if it was that?

Edit: we've had some very sunny days in the past week and I did not get these used to sunlight. I had them indoors next to a window under a grow light that was running 10h / day but that was about it. Could I just be burning them?

Thank you in advance.

[image: leaf]
[image: leaf]
[image: leaf]
[image: leaf]
[image: leaf]
[image: leaf]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like sunburn to me.

Disclaimer: I'm no chili expert. I've grown some chilis myself for 4 years, but only in a room and outdoors, no greenhouse.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you and sorry for the late reply. It was indeed sun burn. I added a 50% shade net and they grew without any more problems. Eventually after a few weeks I removed the net and all seems fine!